# Select past and future values from a given date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a script in python that pulls data from the Data table and populates the Max table. With the given data in the Data table the script should populate the Max table as shown below.

`Max_f` (f stands for future) is the maximum value amongst the 4 items after the current one.

`Max_p` (p stands for past) is the maximum value amongst the 4 items before the current one.

Example for the item `2013-08-13 13:19`:

`max_f` would be the maximum of 21, 24, 28 and 30.

`max_p` would be the maximum of 25, 23, 27 and 26.

The first 4 `max_p` items and the last 4 `max_f` should be n/a because there aren't enough values in the Data table to calculate the respective maximums.

```
          Data                                 Max          
id  datetime          value |   id     datetime       max_f max_p
1   13-Aug-2013 13:15   25  |   1   13-Aug-2013 13:15   27  n/a
2   13-Aug-2013 13:16   23  |   2   13-Aug-2013 13:16   27  n/a
3   13-Aug-2013 13:17   27  |   3   13-Aug-2013 13:17   26  n/a
4   13-Aug-2013 13:18   26  |   4   13-Aug-2013 13:18   28  n/a
5   13-Aug-2013 13:19   25  |   5   13-Aug-2013 13:19   30  27
6   13-Aug-2013 13:20   21  |   6   13-Aug-2013 13:20   31  27
7   13-Aug-2013 13:21   24  |   7   13-Aug-2013 13:21   31  27
8   13-Aug-2013 13:22   28  |   8   13-Aug-2013 13:22   n/a 26
9   13-Aug-2013 13:23   30  |   9   13-Aug-2013 13:23   n/a 28
10  13-Aug-2013 13:24   31  |   10  13-Aug-2013 13:24   n/a 30
11  13-Aug-2013 13:25   29  |   11  13-Aug-2013 13:25   n/a 31
```

I have been trying `SELECT` queries with `INTERVAL` but I am not sure I am approaching the problem in the right way.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Is the "4 items after" determined by a count of items, or is it based on the datetime value? (You mention using `INTERVAL` in your query attempts.) Expanding on your example, for the item at time "`13:19`", if the rows at time "`13:21`" and "`13:22`" were missing from the table, should the `max_f` be '`n/a`', should it be the maximum of just the next two rows: 21, 30, or should it be the maximum of "next" four rows: 21, 30, 31 and 29? That is going to specify how the resultset should be derived. We can throw "try this" queries out, but without a more complete spec, we can't know what query ...

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it, even if it's definitely not in the most efficient class of queries; it bases the interval on 4 minutes back and forward;

```
INSERT INTO `max` (`datetime`, `max_f`, `max_p`) 
  SELECT `data`.datetime, 
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT f.datetime) < 4, NULL, MAX(f.value)),
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT p.datetime) < 4, NULL, MAX(p.value))
  FROM data
  LEFT JOIN data f 
    ON f.datetime > data.datetime
   AND f.datetime < DATE_ADD(data.datetime, INTERVAL  5 MINUTE)
  LEFT JOIN data p
    ON p.datetime < data.datetime
   AND p.datetime > DATE_ADD(data.datetime, INTERVAL -5 MINUTE)
  GROUP BY data.datetime
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b86d3/1).

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` values are truly consecutive, you can do:

```
select d.*,
       (case when sum(dnear.id < d.id) = 4
             then max(case when dnear.id <= d.id then dnear.value end)
        end) as max_p,
       (case when sum(dnear.id > d.id) = 4
             then max(case when dnear.id >= d.id then dnear.value end)
        end) as max_p
from data d left outer join
     data dnear
     on dnear.id between d.id - 4 and d.id + 4
group by d.id;
```

Comment: As noted, this query is dependent on the id value being ascending and contiguous. If there any "gaps" in the id value, or an "`order by d.id`" returns the rows in a different order than "`order by d.timestamp, d.id`", then this query does not meet the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Simple subqueries:

```
SELECT Id,
datetime currdatetime, 
(SELECT Max(Value) FROM Data WHERE datetime < currdatetime AND (SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM Data WHERE datetime < currdatetime) > 4) as MaxP, 
(SELECT Max(Value) FROM Data WHERE datetime > currdatetime AND (SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM Data WHERE datetime > currdatetime) > 4) as MaxF 
FROM Data
```

Comment: I don't believe this meets the specification. I believe it gets the maximum value from ALL rows before or after, not just the closest 4 rows in each direction.

Comment: It takes Max for those which has at least 4 before and afters.

Answer (score 0):

If the specification is to get the maximum value from the four rows before and the four rows after, independent of whether a row for a particular minute is missing), then this query returns the resultset:

```
SELECT d.id
     , IF( ( SELECT 4 AS count_f 
               FROM `Data` f
              WHERE f.datetime > d.datetime
              ORDER BY f.datetime ASC
              LIMIT 3,1
           )
         , GREATEST(
             ( SELECT f1.value FROM `Data` f1
                WHERE f1.datetime > d.datetime
                ORDER BY f1.datetime ASC LIMIT 0,1
             )
           , ( SELECT f2.value FROM `Data` f2
                WHERE f2.datetime > d.datetime
                ORDER BY f2.datetime ASC LIMIT 1,1
             )
           , ( SELECT f3.value FROM `Data` f3
                WHERE f3.datetime > d.datetime
                ORDER BY f3.datetime ASC LIMIT 2,1
             )
           , ( SELECT f4.value FROM `Data` f4
                WHERE f4.datetime > d.datetime
                ORDER BY f4.datetime ASC LIMIT 3,1
             )
           )
         , 'n/a'
         ) AS max_f
     , IF( ( SELECT 4 AS count_p 
               FROM `Data` p
              WHERE p.datetime < d.datetime
              ORDER BY p.datetime DESC 
              LIMIT 3,1
           )
         , GREATEST(
             ( SELECT p1.value FROM `Data` p1
                WHERE p1.datetime < d.datetime
                ORDER BY p1.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1
             )
           , ( SELECT p2.value FROM `Data` p2
                WHERE p2.datetime < d.datetime
                ORDER BY p2.datetime DESC LIMIT 1,1
             )
           , ( SELECT p3.value FROM `Data` p3
                WHERE p3.datetime < d.datetime
                ORDER BY p3.datetime DESC LIMIT 2,1
             )
           , ( SELECT p4.value FROM `Data` p4
                WHERE p4.datetime < d.datetime
                ORDER BY p4.datetime DESC LIMIT 3,1
             )
           )
         , 'n/a'
         ) AS max_p
  -- , d.id
  -- , d.datetime
  -- , d.value
  FROM `Data` d
 ORDER BY d.id
```

BUT... this is going to be light dimming query for large sets, due to the correlated subqueries. Those subqueries are going to be dependent on a suitable index with `datetime` as the leading column.